# Ruby Lowest Integer in a multidimensional Array

Tags: ruby, arrays, integer

Let's say that I have a multidimensional array with array's inside of it that each have two numbers. How do I iterate over the entire array and output the lowest number in each array? For example [[4, 6][8, 3]].My attempts at using .min, <=>, and if else statements have not worked.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to list 'all the mins from the arrays', there are lots of ways, here is a simple one:

```
array_of_arrays = [[4,6],[8,3]]

lowest_arrays = array_of_arrays.map {|a| a[0] < a[1] ? a[0] : a[1]}
```

or

```
 lowest_arrays = array_of_arrays.map {|a| a.min}
```

This outputs [4, 3]

Answer (score 2):

Should be as simple as:

```
[[4, 6],[8, 3]].each{|a| puts a.min}
```

or

```
[[4, 6],[8, 3]].map{|a| a.min}
```

... for an array output

Comment: Thanks. I am new at this and a part of the problem was that I did not know that I had to put a comma in between the arrays! I thought that I could butt them up against each other!!

Comment: More idiomatic: `[[4, 6],[8, 3]].map(&:min)`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use flatten followed by min like so:

```
[[4, 6], [8, 3]].flatten.min

=> 3
```

Comment: One of the things that make me Love Ruby is its Array Api, its one of the best out there.

Comment: Thanks! I did't know about flatten!

Comment: The OP wants to "output the lowest number in each array".